# mapping from one filter to another filter before reaching a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

Before finally moving to *servlet s2* I want to pass through 2 filters which are *filter 1* and then *filter 2* in order. Following is the xml file that does these mapping but I do not know how to map filter-1 to filter-2 and then to servlet-2. How should I change this xml to map my way ?

```
    <!-- filter tags -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter-1</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Filters.Filter_1</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Filter-2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Filters.Filter_2</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-1</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-2</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>s2</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- end of filter tags -->
```

Comment: is this not working? it looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the `<filter-mapping>` entries in web.xml determines their order in the filter chain.

So as you have it, they should be chained in the desired order.

It's a good idea to make your filters independent of this order though.

Comment: and how can I make it independent ?

Answer (score 0):

With this configuration

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-1</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-2</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you request /s2 your request will follow the next steps:

1. filter 1
2. filter 2
3. s2
4. filter 2
5. filter 1

Take a look to the [doc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html).

The code of your filter should look like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

    try {

        // your code for step 1 or 2

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

        // you code for step 4 or 5

    } catch (Exception e) {

        log.error("error" + e.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: how will it make it to filter 2 and then filter 1 in the fourth and fifth step ? I haven't modified the response object

Comment: Let's take filter1 as example. In step1, it is execute the code about `chain.doFilter(...)`. In setep 5, the code after. So, if there is no code after `chain.doFilter(...)`, nothing is done